# How to copy values from one table to another

Tags: r

I have two data frames that have been grouped together (rbind or Union in SQL). The data could be better represented as now the user sees two rows instead of seeing one. Concretely, the user would like to see hotel rates along with other hotel info in one line instead of two (two because of the rbind- dummy columns had to be created to match the number of columns). Below is an example of what is to be achieved (Note that the properties do not match in both data frames):

```
df1 <- data.frame(Property = paste0("Property", "_", letters[1:30]),Dates = seq.Date(as.Date("2018-08-01"), as.Date("2018-08-10"), "d"), RateAmount = abs(rnorm(10) * 200),
                      Occupancy = NA)

df2 <- data.frame(Property = paste0("Property", "_", letters[1:10]),Dates = seq.Date(as.Date("2018-08-01"), as.Date("2018-08-10"), "d"), RateAmount = NA, 
                      Occupancy = rnorm(rnorm(10) * 200, mean = 85))

rbind(df1, df2)
```

The whole purpose of the first table is to gather Hotel Rates (RateAmounts) while the second table (the last 10 rows) has everything needed except RateAmounts. I would like to transfer the RateAmount info (non-NA) to df2 and essentially get rid of df1 (to wind up with single rows instead of two per 'property'). I tried different joins (using dplyr on dates) to no avail. Thank you in advance

Comment: `df1$RateAmount=df2$Occupancy[match(df1$Property,df2$Property)]`

Comment: Or perhaps `df2[is.na(df2)] <- df1[is.na(df2)]; df2`?

Comment: Sorry guys I failed to mention that the properties do not match. df1 (with the RateAmount) has 3 times the number of properties of df2. I will update that in the post. The only match is the Dates column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do the equivalent of a join. R's `merge` can accomplish this nicely.

First pre-process the data getting rid of the NA columns in the dataframes:

```
df1_new <- df1[,-4]
df2_new <- df2[,-3]
```

Next merge:

```
merge(df1_new, df2_new)
```

Merge has parameters to control the columns to be merged by and and which data rows to keep in case there isn't a match.

Alternatively in one line: `merge(df1[,-4],df2[,-3])`

This keeps only matched values:

```
         Property      Dates  RateAmount Occupancy
1  Property_a 2018-08-01  77.0288921  84.97796
2  Property_b 2018-08-02 234.1155289  84.67847
3  Property_c 2018-08-03 347.3747234  86.52871
4  Property_d 2018-08-04   0.7615909  85.14532
5  Property_e 2018-08-05  71.6080894  83.76476
6  Property_f 2018-08-06 171.5747186  86.05425
7  Property_g 2018-08-07  67.7377617  83.22948
8  Property_h 2018-08-08  23.6833664  86.16361
9  Property_i 2018-08-09 468.6021860  82.85337
10 Property_j 2018-08-10 250.3918442  85.03492
```

If you wanted to keep all values you could for example set all = TRUE

```
merge(df1[,-4],df2[,-3],all=TRUE)

      Property      Dates  RateAmount Occupancy
1   Property_a 2018-08-01  77.0288921  84.97796
2   Property_b 2018-08-02 234.1155289  84.67847
3   Property_c 2018-08-03 347.3747234  86.52871
4   Property_d 2018-08-04   0.7615909  85.14532
5   Property_e 2018-08-05  71.6080894  83.76476
6   Property_f 2018-08-06 171.5747186  86.05425
7   Property_g 2018-08-07  67.7377617  83.22948
8   Property_h 2018-08-08  23.6833664  86.16361
9   Property_i 2018-08-09 468.6021860  82.85337
10  Property_j 2018-08-10 250.3918442  85.03492
11  Property_k 2018-08-01  77.0288921        NA
12  Property_l 2018-08-02 234.1155289        NA
13  Property_m 2018-08-03 347.3747234        NA
14  Property_n 2018-08-04   0.7615909        NA
15 Property_NA 2018-08-07  67.7377617        NA
16 Property_NA 2018-08-08  23.6833664        NA
17 Property_NA 2018-08-09 468.6021860        NA
18 Property_NA 2018-08-10 250.3918442        NA
19  Property_o 2018-08-05  71.6080894        NA
20  Property_p 2018-08-06 171.5747186        NA
21  Property_q 2018-08-07  67.7377617        NA
22  Property_r 2018-08-08  23.6833664        NA
23  Property_s 2018-08-09 468.6021860        NA
24  Property_t 2018-08-10 250.3918442        NA
25  Property_u 2018-08-01  77.0288921        NA
26  Property_v 2018-08-02 234.1155289        NA
27  Property_w 2018-08-03 347.3747234        NA
28  Property_x 2018-08-04   0.7615909        NA
29  Property_y 2018-08-05  71.6080894        NA
30  Property_z 2018-08-06 171.5747186        NA
```